# Помогите пожалуйста, с объектами

Tags: javascript, объекты

Мне нужно чтобы линии вертикальные и горизонтальные двигались таким образом, чтобы создавалось ощущение 3-мерной линейной плоскости сделать это можно следующим образом

1. чем ближе приближается к центру вертикальная линия тем больше уклон даётся по х и уходя за рамки они снова создаются слева
2. горизонтальные линии приближаясь к низу увеличивают скорость приближения, их должно быть определенное количество, и самая верхняя должна не двигаться
3. все это делается нажатием кнопок, и изменением параметров в объекте, я не понимаю почему объект не определён, и как сделать изменение context.LineTo

```
<html><body><canvas id="myCanvas" width="501" height="501"></canvas></body><script>
      function ramb(){   
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var v = Math.floor(Math.random() + Math.random()+Math.random()*12);
      var q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m;   
      i = 0; o = 1; p = 2; a = 3; s = 4; d = 5; f = 6; g = 7; h = 8; j = 9;

      context.bеginPath;
      context.moveTo(0, 200);
      context.lineTo(151,100);
      context.lineTo(200,150);
      context.lineTo(250,170);
      context.lineTo(300,150);
      context.lineTo(401,50);
      context.lineTo(500,200);
      context.closePath();
      context.strokeStyle = "black";
      context.stroke();


        //Рамки
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(1, 200);
    context.lineTo(500,200);
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(0, 500);
    context.moveTo(500, 0);
    context.lineTo(0, 0);
    context.moveTo(500, 0);
    context.lineTo(500, 500);
    context.closePath();
    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.stroke();


   var k = {
    //горизонтальные линии
     "28":   context.beginPath(),
     "1":    context.moveTo(-10, 220),
     "2":    context.lineTo(500, 220),
     "3":    context.moveTo(-10, 250),
     "4":    context.lineTo(500, 250),
     "5":    context.moveTo(-10, 300),
     "6":    context.lineTo(500, 300),
     "7":    context.moveTo(-10, 400),
     "8":    context.lineTo(500, 400),
     "9":    context.moveTo(-10, 500),
    "10":    context.lineTo(500, 500),
      //вертикальные линии
   "11":    context.moveTo(40,200),
   "12":    context.lineTo(0,300),
   "13":    context.moveTo(110,200),
   "14":    context.lineTo(20,500),
   "15":    context.moveTo(200,200),
   "16":    context.lineTo(150,500),
   "17":    context.moveTo(300,200),
   "18":    context.lineTo(360,500),
   "19":    context.lineTo(430,500),
   "20":    context.moveTo(390,200),
   "22":    context.lineTo(480,500),
   "23":    context.moveTo(460,200),
   "24":    context.lineTo(500,300),
   "25":    context.closePath(),
   "26":    context.strokeStyle = "red",
   "27":   context.stroke(),
       }
       }



       function ger(){ setInterval(ramb,1000);}
</script></body><body><button onclick="ramb()">XXX</button></body></html>
```

Comment: бардак какой-то, почему у вас св-ва объектов это результат функций рендера? moveTo https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/moveTo вообще ничего не возвращает

Comment: А что здесь такого??

Comment: @ThisMan, так как этот объект нигде не используется его можно вообще удалить :)

Comment: _я не понимаю почему объект не определён_ - какой именно объекте не определен?

Comment: @Grundy если его удалить то вызовы, которые все-таки рисуют на канве, когда этот объект инициализируется, ничего и не нарисуют

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, вызовы можно оставить :)  объект удалить :)

Comment: мне кажется проще посчитать честную перспективу, чем заниматься вот этим

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а тут не честная?

Comment: @Grundy  тут нет ни одной формулы=) может эти линии и образуют перспективу, но как пересчитать эти линии, чтобы понять как они выглядят с другой точки обзора ?? по мне так нужна модель, положение которой будет пересчитано в каждом кадре с учетом положения наблюдателя.

Comment: @Grundy в смысле не честная?

Comment: это я у @StrangerintheQ уточнял, он пояснил в комментарии выше

Comment: @Grundy Что значит честная перспектива? не нашел в интернете...

Comment: @MakarovDs, имелась ввиду обычная перспектива, которую можно рассчитать с помощью формул, относительно какого-то наблюдателя

Comment: https://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS791E/Notes/PerspectiveProjection.pdf

Comment: я не предлагаю пользоваться формулами отсюда, там вменяемые картинки, чтобы понять о чем идет речь